# Dynamic append jquery row values array not inserting in mysql code attached

Tags: php, pdo

php pdo dynamic append jquery row values array not inserting in mysql code attached.. pls help me
when i try to submit the form i got the following error

"Something went wrong. Please try again" also records not inserted.
Please kindly help me what error i done.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$items = (isset($_POST['items']) && is_array($_POST['items'])) ? $_POST['items'] : array();


$sql ="INSERT INTO tis_expenses(expenses_date,expenses_acname,expenses_descrip,length) VALUES(:expenses_date, :expenses_acname, :expenses_descrip, :length)";
$query= $dbh -> prepare($sql);

    foreach ($items as $item)  {   
    $query->bindValue(':expenses_date', $item['expenses_date']);
    $query->bindValue(':expenses_acname', $item['expenses_acname']);
    $query->bindValue(':expenses_descrip', $item['expenses_descrip']);
    $query->bindValue(':length', $item['length']);     

        $query->execute();        
    }
$lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
if($lastInsertId)
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Expenses Added Sucessfull!');</script>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'testingrow.php'; </script>";
}
else 
{
$error="Something went wrong. Please try again";
}

}
?>

javascript code:

function addRow() {

    $('#addr' + numRows).html("<td class='heading'></td><td><input type='date' name='items[][expenses_date]' class='form-control' value='<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>' tabindex='" + (ti++) + "' /></td><td><input type='text' name='items[][expenses_acname]' class='form-control' tabindex='" + (ti++) + "' /></td><td><input type='text' name='items[][expenses_descrip]' class='form-control' tabindex='" + (ti++) + "' /></td><td class='length'><input name='items[][length]" + numRows + "' type='text' class='length form-control input-md' value='' tabindex='" + (ti++) + "' /></td>");

my form code like:
 <td><input type="text" name="items[][expenses_acname]" class="form-control" required></td>
```

Comment: Are you connecting to the database anywhere?

Comment: sorry i forgot to post my dbconnection . following my dbconnection..
<?php
//invoice.php  
include('includes/config.php');
?>

Comment: Please update the code in question not in the comments.

Comment: What is `$dbh`? Can you get the exact error message?